# Properly Saving to file with a file name

Tags: c++, save

```
 ofstream myfile;
    string s=r->str_name+".txt";
    myfile.open (s);
```

where r->str_name is a string.  If r->str_name was "animals" , would it save the file as animals.txt if i concatenate like this?

Comment: Why don't you try it ?

Comment: `ofstream myfile( (str_name+".txt").c_str() );` `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Close. It does do as you expect in that `r->str_name` will be "animals.txt" but to pass it to `myfile.open()` you have to turn it into a `const char*` like so:

```
myfile.open (s.c_str());
```